# What is the most efficient desktop to install with mini.iso?

Tags: system-installation

I have a friends previously xp machine, that is about 10 years old. It only boots through CD but I've made two different CD-R's with Lubuntu and it won't take. I do get mini-iso to load, and have installed Lubuntu, but is there a more efficient desktop than Lubuntu-desktop?

The computer has 256mb RAM, and when I had Lubuntu-Desktop installed half of it was used up by the desktop. The machine loads Chrome well enough and plays youtube videos barely, but getting movies to play through xbmc/vlc is almost impossible (even logging out and logging in directly to xbmc).

So is there any other desktop I can install other than `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` that would allow the computer to browse/watch movies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lightest desktop you can install from mini.iso or from a full iso is Lubuntu (LXDE). 
But if you have installed an Ubuntu desktop (or Lubuntu desktop etc.) you can switch to [IceWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceWM), [JWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JWM), [i3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_%28window_manager%29) or other very light window managers.

I would recommend IceWM as a good alternative because there where a debian menu preinstalled and it is very easy to install.

Here is a memory usage overview:

[image] 
Soure: [A Memory Comparison of Light Linux Desktops on l3net](http://l3net.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/a-memory-comparison-of-light-linux-desktops/)

---

**To install IceWM run this:**

```
sudo apt-get install icewm
```

More info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IceWM

LXDE vs IceWM

[image]
[image]

---

**To install JWM run this:**

```
sudo apt-get install jwm
```

To customize the JWM menu you have to create this file `$HOME/.jwmrc`

A good jwmrc example file: [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=174188&page=2&p=10242452#post10242452)

---

**To install i3** run this in a terminal:

```
# login to the root shell for one 'echo' command
sudo -i
echo "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(lsb_release -c -s) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
logout
# we're back our user account
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install sur5r-keyring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i3
```

Source: [brentwalther.net](http://www.brentwalther.net/blog/how-to-replace-unity-with-i3-window-manager-on-ubuntu-1204)

i3 user guide -> http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html

Answer (score 1):

I have an old XP machine with 256 MB, and I use XFCE, so [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) would probably be your best option.

Comment: could I just type: 
sudo apt-get install xfce and be fine?

Comment: @Michaeljwjr that's what I did, but I thought that it being just XFCE would make it faster, there are still some parts of it that slow down mine.

Comment: XFCE (Xubuntu) has higher system requirements (512MB RAM) than LXDE (Lubuntu) and should be run slower on such an machine.

Comment: @Xubu my mistake, I thought it was the other way round!